# Replace /app route with /web in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I want to replace /app route with something else (say, /web) in my angular app.
For example -
I have the following URL that works as of now -

[www.example.com/app/dashboard](http://www.example.com/app/dashboard)

I want to replace /app with /web.
So if next time I hit ->

[www.example.com/web/dashboard](http://www.example.com/web/dashboard) -> /web is automatically replaced by /app and regular flow continues

And, it should happen for all the other URL endpoints in the app as well.

[www.example.com/web/myprofile](http://www.example.com/web/myprofile) `automatically changes to`
[www.example.com/app/myprofile](http://www.example.com/app/myprofile)

[www.example.com/web/cricketmatch](http://www.example.com/web/cricketmatch)
`automatically changes to` [www.example.com/app/cricketmatch](http://www.example.com/app/cricketmatch)

[www.example.com/web/johnwick](http://www.example.com/web/johnwick) `automatically changes to`
[www.example.com/app/johnwick](http://www.example.com/app/johnwick)

It internally handles such route replacement. Also, the current /app URL should also work as it is. So basically, both the scenarios should work

`www.example.com/app/johnwick` and `www.example.com/web/johnwick` opens the same page, it's just that when I hit /web it changes to /app

Any tips for the above requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your router:

```js
{
    path: "web",
    redirectTo: "app"
}
```